# JSR 283 Query and Seaching

Tags: repository, jsr170

I am in the early stage of a tagged document repository using Apache Jackrabbit.

My initial exploration was with JSR 170. Upon learning that JSR 283 deprecates things like XPath, I began to look more at JSR 283. My (still quite ignorant) impression is that JSR 283 moved to a more SQL-centric API, although the underlying node structure remains the same.

For my application, I would like to have scored tag searches and be able to search tags using regular expressions (although scoring becomes more complex in that case).

My questions are these:

Should I pursue using non-deprecated API features in JSR 283 for this project?
If so, where (or how) would I find information on JSR 283 API for such an application?

Comment: After searching for more information on JSR 283, I've concluded that the best (and perhaps only) source for what I need is the JSR 283 reference implementation available at Day Software.   http://www.day.com/day/en/products/jcr/jsr-283.html

Comment: http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html